# Is there a way to change add test suffix for JS/TS mocha tests

Tags: javascript, testing, intellij-idea, mocha.js

Based on the description there are default file suffixes, where tests are expected. 
[Docs](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/running-unit-tests-on-mocha.html#ws_mocha_navigation)

So it is easy to navigate to them, from the source.

I would like to add `.it.` suffix, as a recognizable test extension, but could not find where to set it. Is there is way?

Answer (score 0):

Patterns used for **Go to test** are hardcoded to `*Spec.js`, `*_spec.js`, `*-spec.js` (+same patterns with `"test"` instead of `"spec"`).

There is currently no way to add more patterns to the list. We have a feature request for making patterns configurable, [WEB-29053](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-29053); please feel free to vote for it